# Find out system locale from PHP script on linux

Tags: php, linux, locale

I'm trying to find out system locale from PHP script on Debian. The way I do:

```
    <?php
    $out = shell_exec('locale');
    print_r($out);
    ?>
```

Result:

```
    LANG=C
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="C"
    LC_NUMERIC="C"
    ...
```

But when I write 'locale' command in my system console I get 'right' result:

```
    LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    ...
```

What is the right way to get system locale from PHP script?

**Overall purpose:**
In the request I accept a file path, which can contain cyrillic symbols. Then I need to access files in this directory. So I want to make my php script work with systems which use different locales (e.g. ru_Utf8, Koi8-r).

Comment: Are you sure that the system locale is truly the *system's* locale, and not just your user's locale?

Comment: Apache with php module is run under 'www-data' user.  I supposed that php would return its locale, but I'm not sure.   From command line 'locale' command returns utf8 under www-data.

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/default/locale`?

Comment: @zneak it's empty.  Please,  read my edit of question,  it may state the problem more clearly,  thx :)

Comment: Any reason not to have locale be set based on a data point in the user table?

Comment: If I understand you right you mean that user should choose encoding by itself. In this case I don't think I should rely on it. And it seems to be more work for user while script can get this info by itself.

Answer (score 1):

*One method* to get the true system locale from PHP:

1) create a .sh script containing the `locale` command (and of course the `#!/bin/bash` header)

2) Add to /etc/sudoers `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/locale.sh` with the sh script you just created

3) Update your PHP `shell_exec` to `$out = shell_exec('sudo /bin/bash /path/to/locale.sh')`

This would allow locale to execute as root, without requiring a password.

Comment: I wouldn't advise modifying the sudoers file just for the sake of reading environment variables. Besides, how can you be sure that root wil have `ru_RU.UTF-8`?

Comment: You can't be sure.  But when someone asks for "system" state, my mind defaults to the root user in linux as being the "system".
Also agree it's silly to mess with sudoers for something like this.

Comment: @zneak thx for answer,  I think that I won't be granted rights  to do this staff on server. Please,  check my edit on question it states the problem more clearly.